# Putting Text into horizontally UIScrollView and appropriate AutoLayout - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, uiscrollview

So I want to create a `Slider` on the top of the `UI`, each item representing a `Category` (there will be five items). I don't want to switch to another `Controller`, when sliding to another `Category`, I just want to load new data into the current `controller`. So I guess the `UIScrollView` is the way to go.

See here for what I want to realize:
[image]

I have trouble now to show the name of the chosen Category in the middle of the Slider, and by the same time on the left and right its neighbors. 
Using a effective AutoLayout is a also necessary.

Is putting Panels into the UIScrollView the right way? 
I am new to iOS-Development and would appreciate any help.

Comment: you can use library for this if you want... and yes there is no problem to put a panel into scrollview

Comment: I found this https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController as library. But it switches between Controllers and it is also managing a TableView, which I don't need. Can you show me a appropriate library?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `scrollview` to the top of your controller, in code configure `scrollcontentwidth` to screenWidth*5 and on each swipe change reload the data of your controller.